# How can I get place details via getDetails in specific language?

Tags: google-places-api

Having placeId I need to get place details. I can do this with the following code:

```
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement("div"));
        service.getDetails({
            placeId: locationReference
        }, parseLocationDetailResponse.bind(null, function(addressObject) {
            deferred.resolve(addressObject);
        }));
```

How can I manually specify language for place details object?

Comment: refer [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-language) and localization section in  [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics)

Comment: so, if I want to switch languages dynamically, I should reload google maps script dynamically too. Am I right?

Comment: Google map will reload automatically you don't need to do that

Comment: could you provide full example?

Comment: will provide u tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Google maps provides [list](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport) of languages you need. Simple adding the `&language=(type of language)` in script `scr`

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
 html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&language=ja"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I switch language dynamically in javascript code?

Comment: You can't switch languages dynamically instead you can create new webpage ,assign the new language and load it from homepage