# Google Places Library - Place Details in specific language - Angular

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I am designing a website that requires displaying an address in two different languages. So when an address is found using **Places API**, I then want to call **Place Details library** to get the exact same location using the returned **place_id**, in a different language.

I know it is possible to pass in "language" parameter when calling **Place Details** via the Rest endpoint:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json
```

However, I am unable to call this endpoint direct from the browser due to it causing CORS error. So am trying to use the **Places Details Library**, which I understand is the recommmended way to get a place using place_id from the browser.

The code (in Typescript as I am using Angular) looks like this:

```
    const hongkong = new google.maps.LatLng(22.396427, 114.109497);
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: hongkong,
      zoom: 15
    });

    const request = {
      placeId: 'ChIJ1dtIFc34AzQRCO1vC37fQ_w',
      language: 'zh-HK',
      fields: ['name', 'address_component', 'type', 'formatted_address', 'geometry']
    };
    const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
      console.log(place);
      console.log(status);
    });
```

This request works, and the result is shown in my browser console. **But**, the results are not returned in the requested language. 
Unfortunately there is nothing in the documentation that suggests the **language** can be passed into the request either.

Docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details

It is possible to request **Place Details** in a specific language using the rest endpoint as mentioned above, but not using their **Places Library** which is really inconsistent.

I know it's possible to set the language of the **Map** at the start like so:
 `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&language=ja"></script>`
But this isn't dynamic and would require a page reload if I wanted to get the same place in a different language.

Does anyone know of a way to request the place details in a specific language using the Places Library, without having to do a reload of the map javascript in between?

**UPDATE**

As a workaround, I am calling `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json` rest endpoint via a proxy server to avoid the CORS issue.

But would really prefer to use the **Places Library js** to make the request directly from a browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get place details via getDetails in specific language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704931/how-can-i-get-place-details-via-getdetails-in-specific-language)

Comment: There is no language parameter, as you already found out from the docs. So if there is no listed parameter, it means you can't set one. Alternatively, as you also found out, you can query the web service in a specific language. Use AJAX and call a controller (server) that will do the query and return the results to your frontend.

Comment: All what you already knew, yes. But your question sounds like you just needed someone to confirm what you found out. You can't set a language with the place details request in the JS API. You can do it with the web service. Why not use the solution that you already have?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Fair point. Thank you for your response. Apologies for my rather brash response earlier (which seems a mod has now removed). The reason I would prefer to use the Places Library js API is for consistency. As I am already using Angular Google Map (AGM) library for doing Place autocomplete (which I think uses Places Library underneath). And I also want to avoid unnecessary load on my server by proxying calls through it.